# Progress bar reading from SQL through php

Tags: php, sql, progress-bar

I am trying to create a progress bar that reads from a sql server. The field in the SQL server will be numbered from 25 - 100. The current code i have is as followed:

```css
    .outer{
     height:18px;
     width:50px;
     border:solid 1px #000;
    }
    .inner{
     height:18px;
     width:<?php echo $percent ?>%;
     border-right:solid 1px #000;
     background: #f8ffe8; /* Old browsers */
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f8ffe8 0%, #e3f5ab 33%, #b7df2d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f8ffe8), color-stop(33%,#e3f5ab), color-stop(100%,#b7df2d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f8ffe8 0%,#e3f5ab 33%,#b7df2d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
     background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f8ffe8 0%,#e3f5ab 33%,#b7df2d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
     background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f8ffe8 0%,#e3f5ab 33%,#b7df2d 100%); /* IE10+ */
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f8ffe8 0%,#e3f5ab 33%,#b7df2d 100%); /* W3C */
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f8ffe8', endColorstr='#b7df2d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    }
```

```html
    <?php
    include ('connect.php');

    //select database to work with
    $selected = mysql_select_db("yerongashs",$connect)
     or die("could not select table");
     
    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * From repairs");

    $percentage = mysql_query("SELECT Status FROM REPAIRS");

    echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Status</th></tr>";
    echo "</thead>";

    echo "<tbody>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "<tr><td>";
     echo $row['FirstName'];
     echo "</td><td>";
     echo $row['LastName'];
     echo '</td><td class="outer">';
     echo '<div class="inner">';
     echo $row['Status'];
     echo '</div>';
     echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    //close connection
    mysql_close($connect);
    ?>
```

I have been working on this for the past 2 days at work and just can't seem to get it working correctly. I am fairly new at PHP and SQL. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your issue or question? note - your css is `.outter` but your html is `class="outer"`

Comment: I have fixed that code up. ok so I want to create a progress bar that goes by the number that's stored in a sql table (jobs) called status. the value stored in that table column will be 25,50,75 and 100. this will give the students an idea how much longer until their laptop is ready to be collected.

Comment: issues I see - (1) `.outter` vs `class="outer"`, (2) `echo '/div>';` should be `echo '</div>';`, (3) since you set `.inner { width:<?php echo $percent ?>%;}` all your `class="inner"` will have the same width, not based off the percent.

Comment: code issue 1 & 2  have been corrected. How would I go ahead and make the .inner the width of the value that is show in the table column "Status"?

Comment: You could set it in your php loop - `... echo '<div class="inner"  style="width:'.$row['Status'].'%;">'; ...` instead of hard coding it in your css class.